# W3 CSS and Body Scroll Lock

Tags: html, css, w3-css

When using any scroll body lock package such as [body-scroll-lock](https://github.com/willmcpo/body-scroll-lock), [react-scrolllock](https://github.com/jossmac/react-scrolllock), or [tua-body-scroll-lock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tua-body-scroll-lock) with the W3 CSS package it does not lock the body if even if the element passed to it is active or open(modal) regardless of what I do.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that W3 declares `html {overflow-x: hidden}` which seems to conflict with the overflow values being set with the body scroll lock packages. If you remove that it seems to fix the issue.